# cannot parse the list of objects from Many2one relation

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.0

I created 2 models: Firm and Node, each firm can have many nodes: So these are my classes:

```
class Node(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default='node', max_length=32)
    firm = models.ForeignKey(
        'Firm',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
class Firm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

What I want to do is to show the list of my nodes in the firm view, this is what I tried: I created the view method:

```
def firm_detail_view(request, id):
    object = Firm.objects.get(id=id)
    context = {
        'object': object,
        'nodes': Node.objects.filter(firm__id__=id)
    }
    return render(request, "node/firm_detail.html")
```

This is my firm_detail page:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    {{ object }}
    <h1>Firm: {{ object.name }}</h1>
    {{ nodes }}
    {% for instance in nodes %}
        <p>{{ instance.id }} - {{ instance.name }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Whenever I call I got this FieldError:

```
Unsupported lookup '' for AutoField or join on the field not permitted.
```

Answer (score 0):

change Node.objects.filter(firm__id__=id) to Node.objects.filter(firm__id=id), the trailing underscores are not needed

Answer (score 0):

Trailing underscores are not needed firm__id__ -> firm__id. Also you can directly use firm=object for join.